# How to change the sampling rate of the data

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, resampling

How to change the sampling rate of the data in the list `result`.

The current sampling rate is 256, but the desired sampling rate is 250.

Given:

- `result` - a list of data with a sampling frequency of 256.
- `buf.size` - the amount of signal in the channel

I tried to use [`scipy.signal.resample`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html)

```
from scipy import signal
result250 = signal.resample(result, buf.size, t=None, axis=0, window=None)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "****.py", line 82, in <module>
    result250 = signal.resample(result, buf.size, t=None, axis=0, window=None)
  File "****\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 1651, in resample
    X = fft(x, axis=axis)
  File "****\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 249, in fft
    tmp = _asfarray(x)
  File "****\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 134, in _asfarray
    return numpy.asfarray(x)
  File "****\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 105, in asfarray
    return asarray(a, dtype=dtype)
  File "****\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 3.3126, 6.6876, 9.3126, 10.0627, ****
```

There is another option of linear interpolation (preferable), but I also can not figure out how to use.
[`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)

Comment: If result is a list of data it's just a series of numbers it has no sampling freq. Can you post a sample of the data and an expected result?

Comment: @nico here's an array of data with a frequency of 256:
3.3126, 6.6876, 9.3126, 10.0627, 9.0626, 6.6876, 4.0626, 2.0625, 0.9375, 0.5625, 0.4375, 0.3125, 0.1875, 0.1875, 0.9375, 2.4375, 4.5626, 6.6876, 7.9376, 7.3126, 4.9376, 1.0625, -3.3126, -6.9376, -8.9376, -8.6876, -6.5626, -3.1875, 0.3125, 2.6875, 3.5626, 2.6875, 0.5625, -2.0625, -4.3126, -5.6876, -5.9376, -5.3126, -4.4376, -3.6876, -3.4376, -3.5626, -3.6876, -3.4376, -2.6875, -1.4375, -0.5625, -0.4375, -1.4375, -3.3126, -5.3126, -6.5626, -6.4376, -5.1876, -3.5626, -2.6875, -3.0625, -4.4376, -5.9376, -6.3126, -5.3126, -2.9375, -0.1875

Comment: @nico It is known that the first data come to `0`, the second - `256`, then `512`, `768`, `1024`, etc.

Comment: Love the GoT reference, however "it is (not) known what type of data this is? or the output desired. Sampling rate just means that the 1st 256 values of the array (what is it voltage?) happened in the 1st second and so on... a python list does not care about that it's just the collection of the values you recorded, if you plot it against an np.arange(0, 1, 1/256) it will be @ 256 Hz if you plot it against an np.arange(0, 1, 1/200) it will be represented in the time dimension as being @ 200Hz... is this what you want? a plot representation?

Comment: @nico Yes, I have data at `np.arange (0, 1, 1/256)`, and the need to interpolate the above range at  frequency `np.arange (0, 1, 1/250)`.

Comment: To understand the error, we need to see the actual code that creates `result`.  Or at least show `type(result)`, `type(result[0])`, `len(result)`.  `resample` should accept a list of numbers with no problem.

Comment: The documentation you linked for `resample` show that it's intended for periodic signals. `interp1d` looks more suitable: you need to supply an array of *x* values, e.g. `np.arange(0, 1, 1/256)`, and you get a function whose values you need to generate for each *x* value in `np.arange(0, 1, 1/250)`.

Comment: @nekomatic Please write an answer to my question with examples. I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must record the time (in seconds - `f.file_duration`).
My answer:

```
x250 = np.arange(0, f.file_duration, 0.004)    #frequency 250
x256 = np.arange(0, f.file_duration, 0.00390625)    #frequency 256

result256 = np.interp(x256, x250, result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try here since the comments are small and I think I'll answer you:

As I was saying python lists are just that, lists, a collection of stuff (not necessarily numerical values) they don't know or care about what is inside and as such they don't know what sampling frequency even means.
Once you accept that the numbers in your list are just a representation of stuff you can sample them at whatever rate you want, it's just a matter of what you plot it against or how many values you consider per unit time.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [3.3126, 6.6876, 9.3126, 10.0627, 9.0626, 6.6876, 4.0626, 2.0625, 0.9375, 0.5625, 0.4375, 0.3125, 0.1875, 0.1875, 0.9375, 2.4375, 4.5626, 6.6876, 7.9376, 7.3126, 4.9376, 1.0625, -3.3126, -6.9376, -8.9376, -8.6876, -6.5626, -3.1875, 0.3125, 2.6875, 3.5626, 2.6875, 0.5625, -2.0625, -4.3126, -5.6876, -5.9376, -5.3126, -4.4376, -3.6876, -3.4376, -3.5626, -3.6876, -3.4376, -2.6875, -1.4375, -0.5625, -0.4375, -1.4375, -3.3126, -5.3126, -6.5626, -6.4376, -5.1876, -3.5626, -2.6875, -3.0625, -4.4376, -5.9376, -6.3126, -5.3126, -2.9375, -0.1875]

x256 = np.arange(0, 1, 1/256)[:len(data)]
x200 = np.arange(0, 1, 1/200)[:len(data)]

plt.plot(x256, data, label='x256')
plt.plot(x200, data, label='x200')
plt.legend()
```

Output:
[image: ![]

Does this solve your resampling problem?

Comment: I think the OP wants the two plots to overlay each other as closely as possible, but the original plot should contain 256 data points and the new plot 250 data points. The actual x (or time) interval is not specified, but the total 'duration' of the data series should be the same for both.

Comment: ahhh... scipy.interpolate.interp1d() will create the function that he wants but usually its for up-sampling not down-sampling. downsampling is just a matter of deleting data...

Comment: Deleting data is a crude method, a better approach would be to fit a function to the original data - using arbitrary equally spaced *x* values - and then find the values of the function for a new sert of differently spaced *x* values. I'm not yet experienced enough with scipy to show how to do that, sadly.

Comment: *" downsampling is just a matter of deleting data..."*  If only it was so simple. :)  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Comment: The total duration may vary, but only slightly (less than 1/250 or 1/256 - as it will)

Comment: @nico please see the main question, where I added a description, because in the comments it is difficult to do.